# Strange line in network debugger

Tags: networking, web, webpack

Can someone explain what is that strange "file"?
I'm using webpack and probably problem with configuration.

[image]

Comment: Please explain little bit more the problem, and share the webpack configuration

Comment: And show us the details of that request

Answer (score 0):

/* Request */

```
Request URL:localhost:8080
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

/* webpack.config.main */

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src'),
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            'angular',
            'angular-ui-bootstrap',
            'angular-ui-router',
            'angular-animate',
            'angular-touch',
            'angular-cookies',
            'angular-sanitize',
            'angular-block-ui',
            'angular-messages',
            'angular-translate',
            'angular-dynamic-locale',
            'angular-translate-loader-static-files',
            'angular-translate-storage-cookie',
            'angular-translate-storage-local'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"] },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|ttf|woff|woff2|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "file-loader?[hash:6].[ext]"
            },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/MerchantApiWeb/**': {
                target: 'http://example.com:8080',
                secure: false
            }
        }
    }
};
```

/* webpack.config.dev.fdp */

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var merge = require('merge');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var GenerateJsonPlugin = require('generate-json-webpack-plugin');

var appName = 'fdp';

module.exports = merge.recursive(true, require('./webpack.config.main'), {
    name: 'dev.' + appName,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
        app: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'app', appName, appName + '.boot.ts')]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build', 'dev', appName)
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'FDP',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'templates', 'fdp.index.ejs'),
            baseUrl: '/'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'app/commons/**/*.html' },
            { from: 'app/fdp/**/*.html' },
            { from: 'app/commons/**/*.json' },
            { from: 'app/fdp/**/*.json' },
            { from: 'app/**/*.js' },
            { from: 'app/fdp/dashboard/directives/banner/assets/**/*' },
            { from: '../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js', to: 'chart.js' },
            { from: '../node_modules/mobile-detect/mobile-detect.js', to: 'mobile-detect.js' }
        ]),
        new GenerateJsonPlugin('version.json', {
            buildDate: (new Date()).toUTCString(),
            name: appName,
            version: 'Alpha'
        })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found!
Just removed

```
devtool: 'inline-source-map'
```

And it works.

Thanks all.